# When I resize an image on Qt, how can I focus to middle point of widget?

Tags: c++, qt, resize, focus

I can change the resolution of an image with a slider. I use `QGraphicsScene` for displaying image.But the problem is when I resize image, I couldn't focus to a point.You can see my code here.

This is first part, so its for resize an image.It's working.

```
void MainWindow::on_sld_scale_valueChanged(int value) {

    //for resize an image with slider

        int w = m_image->width();
        int h = m_image->height();

        int new_w = (w * value)/100;
        int new_h = (h * value)/100;

        m_pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(
                    m_image->scaled(new_w, new_h, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
```

This second part of my function.It is my algorithm for focus to middle point of widget but it doesn't work.

```
//for focus to middle point of widget   

        auto views = m_scene->views();
        Q_ASSERT(views.size() == 1);

        auto view = views.first();

        int pos_x = view->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
        int pos_y = view->verticalScrollBar()->value();

        show_pixmap();

        qDebug() << "x" << pos_x << "w" << view->width()
                 << "sbw" << view->verticalScrollBar()->width()
                 << "y" << pos_y << "h" << view->height()
                 << "sbh" << view->horizontalScrollBar()->height();


        int a = pos_x + (view->width()) + (view->verticalScrollBar()->width());
        int b = pos_x + (view->height()) + (view->horizontalScrollBar()->height());

        a = a * (value/100.0);
        b = b * (value/100.0);

        m_pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(*m_image);
        view->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(a);
        view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(b);
    }
```

This is my source code.I can resize the image but I can't focus to middle point.Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't you mix `QScrollBar::width` to `QScrollBar::maximum`? They have difficult relation.
2. You better don't touch view's scroll bars. Try `QGraphicsView::centerOn` or even `QGraphicsView::fitInView` (did you mean "focus" to be "place to center of the view"?). Like this:

   ```
   const qreal centerX = pixmapItem->x() + pixmapItem->width() / 2;
   const qreal centerY = pixmapItem->y() + pixmapItem->height() / 2;
   viewer->centerOn(centerX , centerY);
   ```

   where `pixmapItem` is a QGraphicsPixmapItem.
3. As @mvidelgauz supposed, why don't you scale a QGraphicsPixmapItem in the scene? May this be a better solution to rescale it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate pixmap, use `QGraphicsView`'s methods `setResizeAnchor()` and `scale()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12789672)

Comment: @JustinWood The question is, if I understand it correctly, how to to focus to the middle point of the widget while scaling it. Then my answer is to use  `setResizeAnchor()`, which is only meaningful in conjunction with `scale()`. Maybe I misunderstood the question...

Comment: Your answer, as it currently is, is more of a comment. You are just telling OP what functions should be used. You should be showing how to do what they are asking. Or at the very least, link to some documentation showing how to accomplish what they are looking for, while copying the most relevant bits of documentation into your answer.

Comment: If you'd like to provide an actual answer, you should explain *how* to do this, and provide some code that's useful to demonstrate.  Otherwise, this is just a comment.